# How do you change the "Cap" value of an []map[string]interface{} in go lang?

Tags: go, ginkgo, gomega

I am trying to do some testing with ginkgo and gomega, I get down to the assertion error

```
Expected
        <[]map[string]interface {} | len:1, cap:1>: []
To equal
        <[]map[string]interface {} | len:1, cap:4>: []
```

I believe that the test is failing because they do not have equal "cap" values, Is there a way to make these cap values equal? Also, would having the items be in different orders cause these test to fail?

thank you

Comment: What is ginko, what is gomega? And no, you cannot control cap of a (used) map.

Comment: ginko is BDD Testing framework and gomega is matcher/assertion library which goes in hand

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13 has an example of making an array with non-default capacity. You might want something like `make([]map[string]interface{}, 1, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

This shows that you have a slice of maps which had some data. This data is now removed. But slice capacity won't decrease. If you need to check if slice is empty, you can go to `BeEmpty` gomega matcher.

If you want an empty slice with known capacity, you can do it like:

```
obj := make([]map[string]interface{}, 4) // 4 is size you need
```

Comment: How would I add data to this after initializiation?

Comment: `obj[0] = your map`

Comment: previously i had it declared like

`
expected = []map[string]interface{}{
    {
     "name":       expectedCompany.Name,
                                       "orders": [] interface {}
                               }
                           }
`

but declaring it like this doesn't seem to work with the new make 4

Comment: ```obj[0] = map[string]interface{}{ "name": your data }```

Comment: I get `expected operand, found '{'`

Comment: now i get `invalid composite literal type interface{}`

Comment: Also, this will cause my tests to break

Comment: you need to go through docs and learn go first. what you're asking here is out of the context for this question

Comment: I dont think this works `obj[0] = map[string]interface{}{ "name": your data }` and I cant find the answer